# Java program doesn't print cyrillic characters, but only question marks

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

my code(Qwe.java)

```
public class Qwe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("тест привет");
    }
}
```

where

> тест привет

is russian words
Qwe.java in UTF-8
on my machine(ubuntu 14.04) result is

> тест привет

on server(ubuntu 12.04) I have:

> ???? ??????

$java Qwe > test.txt
in test.txt is see

> ???? ??????

Comment: My best guess is that it can not interrupt the words and is thus just out putting garbage.

Comment: System.out.println("тест"); is same result - ????

Answer (score 1):

I fix it just use export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it might only accept ASCII characters from the english language unless you have some extension or something. But like I said my best guess is it is not finding the characters and just outputting garbage in their place.

"Java, any unknown character which is passed through the write() methods of an OutputStream get printed as a plain question mark “?”"

as taken from [here](http://alessandrodottavio.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/encoding-something-wrong-java-and-the-question-mark/)

Answer (score 0):

The java source text must use the same encoding as the javac compiler. That seems to have been the case, and UTF-8 is of course ideal.

The the file `Qwe.class` is fine, with internally using Unicode for String. The output to the console uses the server platform encoding. That is, java converts the text in Unicode to bytes using probably the default (platform) encoding, and that cannot handle Cyrillic.

So you have to write to a file, never using FileWriter (a utility class for local files only), but using:

```
... new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8")
```

You can also set user locales on the server but that is not my beer.

In general I would switch to a file logger.

Comment: Its because they are unknown characters to java. You have have to do some more research into getting all uni-code characters to work in java

Comment: @user1182583 In log4j one must set the `encoding` parameter to UTF-8. See http://rhythmcloud.blogspot.de/2009/10/set-character-encoding-to-log4js-file.html

Comment: @jgr208: not entirely, Java uses full Unicode for text, so it can combine any script. However when outputting to bytes, those bytes are in some encoding, and java must be given that encoding, and java's conversion must be able to write that (Cyrillic) character in that encoding. One could do in java `System.out.println("Encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`

Comment: Yes that is true. I never had to deal with java unicode. But I knew basically the output was saying unknown characters.

Comment: now I use new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8").println, but I dont anderstant why in my ubuntu System.out works fine and on server ubuntu I see questionmarks

Comment: @jgr208 Most likely it is as you say, the Linux locale is LC_POSIX or so, and the encoding can only represent ASCII. Linux shell `locale -a` could be the command to check.

Comment: @user1182583 I doubt, trying to write to System.out in a different encoding helps. The operating system must represent it correctly. Sorry. If the OS uses Latin-1 nothing goes to represent Cyrillic correctly.

Comment: LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: That seems as if the problem is more subtle. I am not a Linux expert. Sometimes on Linux there is a locale error, and the system falls back on POSIX which here means ASCII. For Esperanto where there is no designated country eo_XX maybe. For Russion ru_RU.UTF-8 I cannot imagine that. Go to a Ubuntu forum or try different accesses to the server. Try `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` or `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")`. Redirect the output to a file. Sorry.